# gdb doesn't find debug info for local static variables

Tags: c, arm, gdb

I'm having trouble accessing debug information for local static variables with gdb. I created a very simple example that shows the behaviour:

```
int global = 0;
static int g_static = 1;

int main(void)
{
  static int l_static = 2;
  return global + g_static + l_static;
}
```

I compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` (I'm compiling for an MCU target) using `-O0` and `-gdwarf-2` and I can see the debug information for all 3 variables in the output of `objdump -g`:

```
 <1><29>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <2a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x9): global
    <2e>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <2f>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
    <30>   DW_AT_decl_column : 5
    <31>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3c>
    <35>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <36>   DW_AT_location    : 5 byte block: 3 0 0 0 0  (DW_OP_addr: 0)
 <1><3c>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <3d>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 4
    <3e>   DW_AT_encoding    : 5        (signed)
    <3f>   DW_AT_name        : int
 <1><43>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <44>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xac): g_static
    <48>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <49>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 2
    <4a>   DW_AT_decl_column : 12
    <4b>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3c>
    <4f>   DW_AT_location    : 5 byte block: 3 0 0 0 0  (DW_OP_addr: 0)
 <1><55>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <56>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <57>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x17): main
    <5b>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <5c>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <5d>   DW_AT_decl_column : 5
    <5e>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
    <5f>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3c>
    <63>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0
    <67>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x28
    <6b>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x0 (location list)
    <6f>   DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites: 1
 <2><70>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <71>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): l_static
    <75>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <76>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 6
    <77>   DW_AT_decl_column : 14
    <78>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3c>
    <7c>   DW_AT_location    : 5 byte block: 3 0 0 0 0  (DW_OP_addr: 0)
```

In the symbol table `l_static` is given a suffix to make it unique and prevent ambiguity. `nm` output:

```
00000000 b $d
00000000 d $d
00000000 d $d
0000001c t $d
00000000 t $t
00000000 d g_static
00000000 B global
00000000 d l_static.0
00000001 T main
```

Yet when I try to access it using gdb, I can only access debug info for `global` and `g_static` but not for `l_static` or even `'l_static.0'`. It looks like gdb knows about the existence of `l_static.0`but can't find the related debug info.:

```
(gdb) ptype global
type = int
(gdb) ptype g_static
type = int
(gdb) ptype l_static
No symbol "l_static" in current context.
(gdb) ptype 'l_static.0'
type = <data variable, no debug info>
```

I have tried with gdb 7.6.1 and 11.2 with the same result. As far as I understand it the information is there, as shown by the output of `objdump -g`. But for some reason gdb can't find it.
My gut feeling is that this might be related to the way gcc appends the `.0` to the local static's symbol name. Maybe this leads to a mismatch between the symbol name and the name related to the debug info?

Hoping for anyone who can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use gdb & gcc (arm cortex) on a daily basis and static automatic variables are seen without any problerms

Comment: Look at the generated code. I guess that it was optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: but it is in the object file. doesn't that mean the compiler left it in?

Comment: did you stop execution at the return statement? otherwise, it will not be visible in the another scope.

Comment: Try to write a bit less trivial example.

Comment: also, I'm having the same issues in my actual project. and there I know for a fact that the variable isn't optimized out. I can see it's address, it's size but not the type etc.

Comment: try somenthing less trivial https://godbolt.org/z/b4jfs1K4M

Comment: gdb works for millions of programmers without any issues.

Comment: i used -O0 which should keep everything https://godbolt.org/z/jerEqvebo . I'm not claiming that gdb can't do it. It's just that i can't figure out how to tell gdb to give me that information. maybe i should rephrase the question a bit so that is clearer

Comment: @UlliT You can't just start up gdb and expect local variables to be accessible.  It's ambiguous.  You need to set a breakpoint in `main`, then run the program. When the breakpoint inside `main` is reached, *then* the local will be in scope and you should be able to access it.

Comment: @TomKarzes but it's a local _static_ so it has static linkage and I would expect the debug information to be available. in fact, i have done the same thing with a binary generated with the IAR toolchain and it worked. However, the IAR compiler has a different way to make the names of local static variables unambiguous. I'll look into the exact differences in the symbol table and debug info between gcc and IAR

Comment: @UlliT The value is static, yes.  But the *name* is ambiguous.  You might have 10 functions that all have a local with that name.  Do you expect it to randomly pick one?  The name is meaningless *outside of the context of its containing function*.  If you knew its address, then yes, you could print it at any time.  But the name is only meaningful relative to the containing function.  It's lexically scoped.  It's not global.  It needs to be qualified by the function.

Comment: @TomKarzes you are right about the ambiguity regarding the names. see my answer. gdb has a namespace system that lets you access local static variables via <func_name>::<var_name> which resolves any ambiguity

Comment: @UlliT That's a good solution.  It makes sense, and it's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it without running the binary and setting a breakpoint.

```
(gdb) ptype main::l_static
type = int
```

Apparently gdb knows in which function the local static is defined and lets you access it in this c++ namespace-style way, even if the relevant stack frame has not been selected. This is documented in section 10.3 of the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop inside the main function to see that variable:

[image]